# jekyll when I edit the yaml about tags and category in post markdown file then the css doesn't work?

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I use rake to generate a new post. The yaml is

```
category:
tags:[]
```

When I change the yaml like this

```
category:test
tags:[test]
```

the css does not work ...

I use the jekyll bootstrap 's theme the minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space between the colon and the content. Instead of:

```
category:test
tags:[test]
```

Try:

```
category: test
tags: [test]
```

And, of course, make sure your template is setup properly moving forward. I'm not sure about leaving an empty 'category'. I would suggest making your template output `category: default` or the something like that to avoid any issues.

Comment: Happy to help and Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you'll mark this answer as Accepted by clicking on the check mark in the answer that will let other people know that this works for you. Enjoy the site.

Comment: @AlanW.Smith can you add an example how to output a default category?

Comment: @cringe - I'm not sure what you mean. Best bet is probably to open a new question with details on exactly what you are trying to accomplish.